# Samba net command to shutdown Windows 8 machine

Tags: linux, bash, windows-8, shutdown

I have a Raspberry Pi for home automation, and I want to be able to shutdown my Windows 8.1 workstation using a command from a `bash` shell.

Of course I've Googled before asking here. And I found;

```
net rpc shutdown -s [ipadress] -U username%passsword shutdown -t 1 -f
```

The net command only works if you;

```
apt-get install samba-common-bin
```

But that gives me the error;

```
Could not initialise pipe \winreg. Error was NT_STATUS_OBJECT_NAME_NOT_FOUND
```

Of course I have also Googled this error message, but I only find stuff from the Windows XP/Vista age.

Answer (score 0):

try out the domain flag by putting there the name of your machine as the domain. 
are you sure the right environment is set up for this task?  (remote services set up,  user access rights, time synchronization eat)

are you able from another windows machine to accomplish this task via shutdown -m?

Also I would suggest some wmi calls to do that kind of operation